# Install psycopg2 for Ubuntu 18.04 with Python2 and Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-18.04

When I install psycopg2, it's always installing into Python 2.7, but I use Python 3.7. And cannot import psycopg2 into my module. Is there a way to redirect installation? From terminal Python successfully importing psycopg2, and Python3 raise error.

Comment: How are you installing it? Probably use `pip3n instead of `pip`.

Comment: Have you created virtual environments? If so, switch to the 3.7 one before installing the package. If not, make it a habit. :-)

Comment: `python3 -m pip install --user psycopg2-binary`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+different+python+version

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3-psycopg2  This command do it. Only Python 3.7 give error, but Python 3.6 works fine.